# How to get variables out of square roots and collect in order to simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
f = 2 Sqrt[b^3 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] + 8 Sqrt[b^5 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] + 
10 Sqrt[b^7 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] - 10 Sqrt[b^11 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] - 
8 Sqrt[b^13 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] - 2 Sqrt[b^15 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c]
```

If we write (this is the best after I read so many questions in this page):

```
FullSimplify[f, Assumptions -> {a > 1, b > 1, c > 0,
  Element[a, Reals], Element[b, Reals], Element[c, Reals]}, 
    ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount]
```

We obtain (just each coefficient is reduced by a factor 2):

```
(Sqrt[b^3 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] + 4 Sqrt[b^5 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] + 
5 Sqrt[b^7 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] - 5 Sqrt[b^11 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] - 
4 Sqrt[b^13 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] - Sqrt[b^15 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c])
```

We can do this (we see the common part `Sqrt[b (1 + b) (1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) c]`):

```
FullSimplify[(2 b + 8 b^2 + 10 b^3 - 10 b^5 - 8 b^6 - 2 b^7) Sqrt[b (1 + b)  
(1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c], {b > 1}]
```

and *Mathematica* out is:

```
-2 (-1 + b) b (1 + b)^5 Sqrt[b (1 + b) (1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) c]
```

But the problem is that this is a little part of a huge expression and doing this manualy may take weeks or more.

The optimal expresion would be:

```
-2 b (b - 1) (b + 1)^5 Sqrt[b c (b + 1) (1 + b (2 a^2 - 1))]
```

But I will be hilarious with the previous.

### Suplemental question:

As prescribed in the second response by **bbgodfrey**, we obtain our objective! Thanks you very much!

But permit me to go far away, if we put **bbgodfrey**'s solution in a more complex expression like:

```
ff = (a (2 a (-2 + a^2) b^(3/2) - 2 a^3 b^(5/2) - 2 a (-2 + a^2) b^(7/2) + 2 a^3 b^(9/2) + 
Sqrt[2] (-1 + a^2) b Sqrt[(-1 + b) (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] - 6 Sqrt[2](-1 + a^2) b^2 
Sqrt[(-1 + b) (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] + Sqrt[2] (-1 + a^2) b^3 Sqrt[(-1 + b) (1 + b) 
(1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] + (4 a (Sqrt[b^3 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] + 3 Sqrt[b^5 
(1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] + 2 Sqrt[b^7 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] - 2 Sqrt[b^9 
(1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] - 3 Sqrt[b^11 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] - Sqrt[b^13 
(1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c]))/(1 + b)^3 + b (-2 a Sqrt[b] + 2 a (-4 + a^2) b^(3/2) - 
2 a^3 b^(5/2) - 2 a (-4 + a^2) b^(7/2) + 2 (a + a^3) b^(9/2) + Sqrt[2] (-1 + a^2) b 
Sqrt[(-1 + b) (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] - 6 Sqrt[2] (-1 + a^2) b^2 Sqrt[(-1 + b) (1 + b)
(1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] + Sqrt[2] (-1 + a^2) b^3 Sqrt[(-1 + b) (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] + 
4 a (Sqrt[b^3 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c] - Sqrt[b^7 (1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c]))))
/(4 (-1 + b) b^2 (1 + b) (2 a^3 Sqrt[b] + 2 a^3 b^(3/2) + Sqrt[2] (1 + a^2) Sqrt[(-1 + b)
(1 + b) (1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) c]))

FullSimplify[ff /. Sqrt[z1___ z3_^n_ z2___] -> z3^(n/2) Sqrt[z1 z2]]
```

*Mathematica* out is:

```
(a (2 a^3 (-1 + b)^2 Sqrt[b] (1 + b) - Sqrt[2] (1 + (-6 + b) b) Sqrt[(1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) 
(-1 + b^2) c] + Sqrt[2] a^2 (1 + (-6 + b) b) Sqrt[(1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) (-1 + b^2) c] + 
2 a Sqrt[b] (-1 + b^2) (3 + b - 2 Sqrt[(1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c])))/(4 (-1 + b) b 
(2 a^3 Sqrt[b] (1 + b) + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) (-1 + b^2) c] + Sqrt[2] 
a^2 Sqrt[(1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) (-1 + b^2) c]))
```

When we expect:

```
(a (2 a Sqrt[b] (3 + a^2 (-1 + b) + b) (-1 + b^2) + Sqrt[2] (-1 + a^2) (1 + (-6 + b) b) 
Sqrt[(1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) (-1 + b^2) c] - 2 a (-1 + b^2) 2 Sqrt[b (1 + b) (1 + (-1 + 2 a^2)
b) c]))/(4 (-1 + b) b (2 a^3 Sqrt[b] (1 + b) + Sqrt[2] (1 + a^2) Sqrt[(1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b)
(-1 + b^2) c]))
```

Why can we automatize *Mathematica* to collect and reduce the expression length?

We are very interested in adding rules to accomplish a full simplification. What is the estructure of this sentences? We would be very grateful if anybody could explain or give information (other questions, tutorials...) about this.

Thanks to all the people who answers, comments, edits and reads!

Comment: Giving an assumption a>1 should mean you don't then need Element[a,Reals]. If you are sure your assumptions are valid then you might try f /. Sqrt[p_^n_* q_] /; OddQ[n] :> p^((n-1)/2)* Sqrt[p* q] to pull your odd powers outside your square roots.

Comment: After you have extracted even powers of b and stored the result in say ff then you might try Simplify[ff //. p_* Sqrt[q_]+r_* Sqrt[q_]->(p+r)* Sqrt[q]] to collect together all your identical square roots into one. Use this cautiously. Check results carefully.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @Nicolas Jumilla, do not spoil you question and nickname. You've made in intractable. Make a second question separate from the first, starting with the reference to the code. And do not forget to accept the bbgofrey`s answer if you like it.

Comment: Nicolas - please see: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Thank you @Verberia, I have already joined my two account.

Comment: Sorry about spoil my question but I did not know how interact whit you because whit my another account I could not add comments or accept a answer. I do not know if the second question I have done must be in other question separate from the first. Now I agree with @garej that it takes more sense if it would be separate.

Comment: Thanks all, I am very pleased and positive surprise by the good and efficient treatment of this community!

Comment: Before separate the question, I would know @bbgodfrey 's view because he has already answered the second question in this.

Comment: @NicolasJumilla  Ordinarily, it is not good practice to add significantly to the scope of a question after answers have been given.  However, since my expanded answer seems to meet your needs, there is no need to start a new question in this instance.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for expressions of the form in the question but, of course, not for all expressions.

```
Simplify[f /. Sqrt[Times[z1___, b^n_, z2___]] -> b^((n - 1)/2) Sqrt[Times[z1, b, z2]]]
(* -2 (-1 + b) b (1 + b)^5 Sqrt[b (1 + b) (1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) c] *)
```

If the variety of expressions to the simplified is modest, more rules can be developed along these lines to accomplish a full simplification.

**Addendum**

A simpler and more general solution is

```
Simplify[f /. Sqrt[z1___ z3_^n_ z2___] -> z3^(n/2) Sqrt[z1 z2]]
{* -2 (-1 + b) b^(3/2) (1 + b)^5 Sqrt[(1 + b) (1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) c] *}
```

**Second Addendum**

The following largely but not entirely satisfies the goal of the addition to the question.

```
FullSimplify[ff /. b -> d^2 /. Sqrt[z1___ z3_^n_ z2___] -> z3^(n/2) Sqrt[z1 z2], d > 0];
FullSimplify[
  Collect[Numerator[%136], Sqrt[c (1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) d^2) (-1 + d^4)], Simplify]/
  Collect[Denominator[%136], Sqrt[c (1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) d^2) (-1 + d^4)], Simplify] /. 
  d -> Sqrt[b], b > 0]
(* (a (Sqrt[2] (-1 + a^2) (1 + (-6 + b) b) Sqrt[(1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) (-1 +  b^2) c] + 
    2 a Sqrt[b] (-1 + b^2) (3 + a^2 (-1 + b) + b - 
    2 Sqrt[(1 + b) (1 - b + 2 a^2 b) c])))/
   (8 a^3 b^(3/2) (-1 + b^2) + 4 Sqrt[2] (1 + a^2) (-1 + b) b 
    Sqrt[(1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) (-1 + b^2) c]) *)
```

The denominator could be further simplified by using a `ComplexityFunction` that penalizes terms that the OP wishes to eliminate.  However, at some point the approach becomes so specific to the problem that it is equivalent to performing the simplification by hand.

Comment: @bbgofrey, +1 for general solution and `virtual accept` =))

Comment: @bbgodfrey, why does _Mathematica_ not collect in a correct way in `Simplify`? I always though that _Mathematica_ does this because it considers that its output expression is simpler than our expectative. Is there any command or sentence that change _Mathematica_ behavior? Is there a general solution that reduces the length of expressions significantly?

Comment: @NicolasJumilla  `Simplify` attempts to reduce the value of a `ComplexityFunction` by applying `TransformationFunctions`. This fails, if that desired result does not correspond to the lowest value of the `ComplexityFunction` being used or if none of the available `TransformationFunctions` is able to transform the expression to the desired result.  Also, sometimes the needed sequence of transformations first must increase the complexity before reducing it, and `Simplify` may not explore that sequence in sufficient depth to determine that eventually it leads to a less complex result.

Answer (score 3):

Let us take

```
z = Sqrt[b (1 + b) (1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) c]; k = {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0};
```

So

```
z * FullSimplify[f/z, Assumptions -> k]
```

> `-2 (-1 + b) b (1 + b)^5 Sqrt[b (1 + b) (1 + (-1 + 2 a^2) b) c]`

Comment: Your solution is elegant in its simplicity.  The assumption `b > 0` is sufficient, however.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, you are right. The only thing `c = 0` Should be ruled out. Otherwise expression `f/z` will return `Indeterminate`. I kept all of them because of OP's assumption.

Comment: @garej, it is a good idea. We can use in some punctual cases.